# next js warning in browser console

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am moving from react js to Nextjs 13. I'm just creating a simple calculator application but it's showing some warnings.

> The resource http://localhost:3000/%20next/static/css/app/page.css?v=1688433441465 was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

Im creating individual CSS for every component.

Comment: See: [How to fix link preload warning in Next.js app?](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/49607)

Answer (score 1):

[Nextjs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts#using-multiple-fonts) suggests two approches when working with multiple fonts:

### First approach:

> create a utility function that exports a font, imports it, and applies its `className` where needed. This ensures the font is preloaded only when it's rendered:

app/fonts.ts:

```js
import { Inter, Roboto_Mono } from 'next/font/google'
 
export const inter = Inter({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  display: 'swap',
})
 
export const roboto_mono = Roboto_Mono({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  display: 'swap',
})
```

app/layout.tsx:

```js
import { inter } from './fonts'
 
export default function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className={inter.className}>
      <body>
        <div>{children}</div>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

app/page.tsx:

```js
import { roboto_mono } from './fonts'
 
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className={roboto_mono.className}>My page</h1>
    </>
  )
}
```

> In the example above, `Inter` will be applied globally, and `Roboto Mono` can be imported and applied as needed.

### Second approach

> you can create a [CSS variable](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/font#variable) and use it with your preferred CSS solution:

app/layout.tsx:

```js
import { Inter, Roboto_Mono } from 'next/font/google'
import styles from './global.css'
 
const inter = Inter({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-inter',
  display: 'swap',
})
 
const roboto_mono = Roboto_Mono({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--font-roboto-mono',
  display: 'swap',
})
 
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className={`${inter.variable} ${roboto_mono.variable}`}>
      <body>
        <h1>My App</h1>
        <div>{children}</div>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

app/global.css:

```js
html {
  font-family: var(--font-inter);
}
 
h1 {
  font-family: var(--font-roboto-mono);
}
```

> In the example above, `Inter` will be applied globally, and any `<h1>` tags will be styled with `Roboto Mono`.

following one of these two approaches the warning should disappear

Comment: How did you know that the user is importing fonts (or working with multiple ones)? I don't see any fonts mentioned anywhere.

Comment: im only using inter, i haven't try any other fonts styles

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using css modules if you are using multiple css file. Your css file should be named `your-styles.module.css`, `.module.css|scss` is important.

Then in your component

```
import styles from './your-styles.module.css'

...
<div className={styles.someClass}>
...
```

If you are using multiple CSS files per component or page, you can import as follows

```
import styles from './your-styles.module.css'
import styles1 from './your-styles1.module.css'
...
<div className={styles.someClass}>
<div className={styles1.someClass}>
...
```

Comment: actually im using multiple css files for every components and every pages.